# Joined new organisation in lower pay band

Tags: new-job, negotiation, work-experience, payscale

I have worked for a Multi National Company (Software) company for 12 plus years in banking market. I wanted to move to another organisation to experience a change, and to attain market correction to my salary.

I have joined another bank in the IT division, I was hired because of my many years of relevant banking application experience. The new organisation has opened new slots to recruit females in leadership positions.

I am given the pay raise that I asked for but the designation I joined under is one level below where my market value is. Before joining, I have done my research and asked to be moved into the next pay band. The company responded that the current designation is itself a very rare achievement and I am given this because of the female gender promotion initiative.

In reality, even having 8.5 - 10 years are given the current designation, and 10+ years experience irrespective of gender are given the upper level. I have realized this after joining. Leaving out the female part of the equation, I still didn't get what I deserve even in the normal\standard case.

It is demotivating as team members with 3-4 yrs less experience are now my peers and in long run it will be disappointing.

How do I put express this to management in hopes of getting moved into the next pay band?

Comment: What's your actual question?

Comment: I actually feel like there's a good question in there somewhere, but the language barrier is too strong. It's difficult to tell what you're trying to ask, so I'm afraid nobody can help you right now.

Comment: If by band you mean to say designation than I can help edit your question so people get what you're asking...

Comment: You were at an MNC IT company for 12 and half yrs, why did you leave?

Comment: What's an MNC ?

Comment: Multinational Company (MNC) Have edited the quesiton.

Comment: Questions asking for **advice on what to do are not [practical answerable questions](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)** (e.g. *"what job should I take?"*, or *"what skills should I learn?"*). Questions should get answers explaining *why* and *how* to make a decision, not advice on what to do. For more information, click [here](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2695/294).

Comment: I attempted to salvage this question, we'll see what the community thinks.

Comment: "Leave about female elevation" - I don't understand what is meant by this. Can you clarify?

Comment: They have explicitly told you the only reason why you are getting as much as you earn now is because you are a woman, so they don't even rate your actual skill set to be worth what they are currently paying you so the chances of getting more are likely non-existent.

Comment: @DCON "Leave out" I think is what's intended.

Answer (score 4):

### The wrong way to approach this:

> I'm not being paid as much as I deserve.

### The right way to approach this:

> What can I do to improve my standing so that I am able to be promoted?

Ask management that question.  If their answer is "nothing, we just hired you because we had to", you may be simply out of luck: they may be upset that they had to hire more women, and taking it out on you.

But if there are actual technical reasons you're not in that pay band - whether it's time in the job, specific skills, or whatnot - they should be willing to tell you what you can work on improving, and how to get to that next level.

This also means you have a documented explanation for what you need to get the next level - so in a while, you can sit down with them and explain how you've met all of these, and the conversation then becomes:

> Here is the list of things that I've done that show I'm ready to be promoted to the next level.

---

A side note.  One thing I learned from my first professional boss: Pay and responsibility matters more than title.  If you have the same pay and the same responsibility, prefer the *lower* title. That allows you to then get a promotion later on with a significant salary bump without having to argue as much for the raise. So if you were given this job, and the salary you wanted at the lower title?  Be happy!  It means you'll make *more* money in the long run than these folks who got the senior title as youngsters.  They don't have as far up to go now, and less salary probably.